# How to get all the files of a Github repository using Javascript to create an index.html to access all the files

Tags: javascript, github-api

I'm trying to create an easy-access document to all the files of my repository (they are all written in Markdown).

The idea is to make an script in .js that analyzes the repository and lists all the files like links to access to them. (An easy way to see the files from mobile for example)

I've tried to use this code, but it doesn't work to me :/ :

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const url = "https://api.github.com/repos/gitblanc/Obsidian-Notes/contents/"
    // Replace -username- with your GitHub username, -repo- with the repository name, and then :path with a path to the file or folder you want to get the content of (leave blank to ge all files of the repository)

    xhr.open('GET', URL, true);

    xhr.onload = function() {
        const data = JSON.parse(this.response);

        console.log(data);
    };
    
    xhr.send();
```

Comment: Note that this is not *all the files in the repository*, but rather *all the files in a single commit within the repository*.

Comment: Typo: JavaScript is case-sensitive. The `URL` (built-in) and `url` (defined by you) variables are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing in the url parameter.

The request hast to look like this:

```
const url = "https://api.github.com/repos/gitblanc/Obsidian-Notes/contents/"

xhr.open('GET', url, true);
```

You had a typo (all caps) with the url variable.

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow.

Comment: Allright, got you. Didn't know about that. Should I delete the answer, to not block deleting?

Comment: I'd normally recommend that but since it's been accepted as an answer, you can't do that now.